# Create publish profile for MSBuild from command line

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, publish

I use msbuild command to build the solution and use publish profiles to publish to a local folder, This i used to do in VM builds as i can manually create publish profiles and refer the same during build. 
Now, We have a solution of using containerized slaves in jenkins which will handle the build of my .net application. So, its not possible to have those files in containers as it is on-demand containers. I know, we can copy the files into containers while creation, but that's used in worst scenario.
Can you help me in creation of the publish profiles using a command with required arguments, so that the profile will be generated on runtime and the scope will be in the workspace?

Comment: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"  
xxx.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile.pubxml       This is the command we are currently using post copying the publish profiles to the default folder.

Comment: You should create an almost production ready publish profile then copy it and update it just before your building phase, using a powershell script for instance, all within the scope of your workspace.

Comment: I have use msbuild ci projects in the past for this to also allow publishing multiple configurations and projects: https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/625f3ad8c1b49748bb7f6ad8a230bf76 (`msbuild.exe thatfile.proj`)

Comment: @dbrallion yes we need to create a production ready publish profile, but can we do that on the go before building it using msbuild. Like creation of publish profile with certain arguments using a command. Can we do that?

Comment: @MartinUllrich , how to use that *.xml while building.Also, we can write multiple publish commands in that right? like debug build publish, release build publish, deploy to azure publish.

Comment: Also, i realized that if we are using sln file to build, then the corresponding project guid must be mentioned in publishprofile. But when you are using csproj to build the project there is no need for the project guid to be present in the publishprofile. So the code becomes static except configuration(debug/Release) and the target framework, so the content can be modified and converted to a file in jenkins job and copy it to the respective properties folder for the msbuild to access. This way i can create the file on the go. It worked for me! Any issues with this approach?